# Authorization Error getting oEmbed for protected tweets

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

In my simple Node app, I want to get the oEmbed for the first tweet of the logged in user. Currently I'm initiating twit with my app's `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` along with my personal profile's `access_token` and `access_token_secret`. I am then calling

```
T.get('statuses/oembed', params, function(err, data, response) {
    console.log(data);         
})
```

where params is `{id: tweet_id_str}`, and I've even tried hardcoding in the id_str (wrapped in quotes). I've had success getting and deleting a tweet with these credentials and params, but for 'statuses/oembed' I'm getting the following error:

```
{ error: 'Sorry, you are not authorized to see this status.',
  request: '/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id=640736324916383744' }
```

I seem to be able to get embeds for public tweets, but not my personal, protected tweets. Is it simply impossible to get the oEmbed for protected tweets, even when they belong to the logged in user, or is there an additional authorization step that I am missing?